# average temperature in Arduino

Tags: arduino, average, outliers

I have an Arduino thermometer by Sparkfun that measures temperature. It's very precise, but I need more of an average.

The code I'm using is straight from Sparkfun (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sik-experiment-guide-for-arduino---v32/experiment-7-reading-a-temperature-sensor)

```
const int temperaturePin = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  float voltage, degreesC, degreesF;

  voltage = getVoltage(temperaturePin);

  degreesC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100.0;

  degreesF = degreesC * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;

  Serial.print("voltage: ");
  Serial.print(voltage);
  Serial.print("  deg C: ");
  Serial.print(degreesC);
  Serial.print("  deg F: ");
  Serial.println(degreesF);


  delay(1000); 
}


float getVoltage(int pin)
{
  return (analogRead(pin) * 0.004882814);
}
```

I'm looking get a reading every minute on an AVERAGE of every 10 seconds, AND throw out outliers, rather than merely what is is every minute.
FOR EXAMPLE, if it reads 65, 64, 66, 67, 65, 44 over the course of a minute...it will average the first 5 and throw out 44, for an average of 65.4.

Comment: You can calculate which values are outliers by first doing a [five number summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-number_summary)

Comment: One way is to discard the lowest and highest readings and average the rest. There are other ways... google? A more complicated way would be, knowing the possible rate of temperature change, that any change outside of that must *persist* for a defined number of readings.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Average is not opposed to precision. And Arduino is not C or standard C++.

Comment: You have to define WHAT is an outlier.. With 6 samples, it's difficult to say "this is clearly an outlier". What if there are two outliers over 6? and 3? My advice is to keep all of them. If there is noise, make 10 measures in a second and average them for 6 times in a minute (every 10 seconds you start a cycle of 10 measures). Or, if you see that your kind of results is common, exclude the highest and the lowest. I suggest you to do this math in integers, before converting, and do all the conversion in one line, so the compiler can make just one instruction instead of three.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sorting the numbers and computing the average of a few numbers (about 10-25% of the number of samples may be a good start) near the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median). This way you get rid of the outliers quite easy and obtain a relevant average.